# to_python() never gets called (even in case of __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase)

Tags: python, django, django-models

Some time ago, as part of the process of learning Python+Django, I decided to write a custom MySQL-specific model field for the BIT column type. Unfortunately, I've ran into a problem.

**The project:** contains a single "main" app

**The "main" app:** contains all of the standard files created by "python manage.py startapp", plus extfields.py

**The contents of extfields.py are as follows:**

```
from django.db import models
import re
import bitstring

class BitField(models.Field):
    description = 'A class representing a field of type "BIT" (MySQL-specific)'
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        bf_size = int(kwargs.pop('bitfield_size', 0))

        assert bf_size > 0, '%ss must have a positive bitfield_size' % self.__class__.__name__
        self._bf_size = bf_size

        super(BitField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def db_type(self):
        return 'BIT(%d)' % self._bf_size


    def to_python(self, value):
        print('to_python starts')

        if isinstance(value, bitstring.BitArray):
            return value    

        value = str(value)

        regex = re.compile('^[01]{%d}$' % self._bf_size)

        assert regex.search(value) == True, 'The value must be a bit string.'

        print('to_python ends')

        return bitstring.BitArray(bin=value)


    def get_db_prep_value(self, value):
        return value.bin
```

**The contents of models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
import extfields

class MessageManager(models.Manager):
    """
    This manager is solely for the Message model. We need to alter the default
    QuerySet so that we'll get the correct values for the attributes bit field   
    """
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(MessageManager, self).get_query_set().defer(
            'attributes'
        ).extra(
            select={'attributes': 'BIN(attributes)'}
        )


class Message(models.Model):
    attributes = extfields.BitField(bitfield_size=15)

    objects = MessageManager()
```

When I use the python shell (via python manage.py shell), I get the following:

```
>>> from main import models
>>> m = models.Message.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> m
<Message_Deferred_attributes: Message_Deferred_attributes object>
>>> m.attributes
u'1110001110'
>>> type(m.attributes)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> m.attributes = '1312312'
>>> m.attributes
'1312312'
```

As you see, the m.attributes is a plain string, instead of bitstring.BitArray instance.

Could someone please tell me where I've made a mistake?

I'm using Python 2.6.5 on Ubuntu 10.04. The bitstring module I import is this one: http://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/. Python-django package version is 1.1.1-2ubuntu1.3.

**EDIT (in response to emulbreh's comment):**

right now my to_python() definition looks like this:

```
def to_python(self, value):
        print 'to_python'

        if isinstance(value, bitstring.BitArray):
            return value    

        print type(value)    
        value = str(value)
        print'\n'
        print value
        print '\n'
        print type(value)        

        regex = re.compile('^[01]{%d}$' % self._bf_size)

        assert regex.search(value) == True, 'The value must be a bit string.'
        value = bitstring.BitArray(bin=value)
        print '\n'
        print type(value)
        print 'End of to_python'

        return value
```

The console output is:

[image]

After this, an AssertionError is raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special in the QuerySet to support a custom field. You currently `defer()` your field and then add a raw extra(select=) attribute that coincidentally has the same name as your field. 
If you just remove the custom manager (or the .defer().extra() calls) you should be fine.

Comment: Right you are! But, if I use the default manager, a new problem will emerge. If you remove the defer() and extra() calls and just perform "SELECT attributes FROM main_message;", it'll return some bogus value. The manual reads: "Bit values are returned as binary values. To display them in printable form, add 0 or use a conversion function such as BIN()." That is, I need to find a way to process "attributes" with BIN() with to_python() still being called after each query. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/bit-field-values.html for details on BIT type.

Comment: Ignore the second and third sentence. What I was actually trying to say is that I need the unprocessed value of the "attributes" column to be either a Python string representing a bit string, a positive integer, a bytearray object, a tuple or a list. Anything of the above will do, as it's properly handled by the bitstring.BitArray class.

Comment: What do you get if you just select the column?

Comment: A binary value, naturally. If I print it in to_python(), then I'll get the following output: 
�

Comment: Actually, the output doesn't quite look like this. I don't think it's THAT important, but I've added a screenshot at the bottom of my question's block anyway.

Comment: Shouldn't BitString(bytes=value, length=self._bf_size) work then?

Comment: Did you mean bitstring.BitArray(bytes=value, length=self._bf_size)? It DOES create a BitArray object this way. But! The value is **almost** correct, but not completely, which really makes me nervous. In this case, when I do ">>> m.attributes",I get: "BitArray('0b000000111000110')". Alas, the "select BIN(attributes) from main_message;" query fetches "1110001101".

Comment: Wait a minute. When I don't explicitly specify the length attribute, m.attributes.bin returns the correct value (in this case, ">>>m.attributes" returns the hex representation). Hooray! ;) Thank you for your help! (It just leaves me pondering, why does the BitArray store an incorrect value when you specify the length?..)